# Resizing an NSWindow setup as a childwindow

Tags: xcode, macos, nswindow

Let me rephrase the question:

How can I keep a child NSWindow (added to a main NSWindow using `addChildWindow`) the same size as the main window?

**Old question:**

I have two `NSWindow`s: an uiWindow and an openglWindow. The uiWindow is borderless and initially the same size as the openglWindow. I add it as a child window. I would like to make the uiWindow follow any size changes that the openglWindow undergoes. To do that, I've subscribed to the delegate of openglWindow and I'm listening to the `windowWillResize` method. However, I'm confused now. I don't know which function to call on uiWindow to resize it. There are quite a few options:

- `setFrame: display:`
  `
- `contentRectForFrameRect`
- `frameRectForContentRect`

Below is the initialization code for the child window.

```
NSRect uiWindowRect = [self.openglWindow convertRectToScreen:((NSView*)self.openglWindow.contentView).bounds];
NSWindow* uiWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:uiWindowRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreNonretained defer:NO];

[self.openglWindow addChildWindow:uiWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way that does exactly what I was looking for. Here's the code for reference:

```
-(void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.openglWindow.frame.origin.x,self.openglWindow.frame.origin.y, ((NSView*)self.openglWindow.contentView).frame.size.width, ((NSView*)self.openglWindow.contentView).frame.size.height);
    [self.window setFrame:frame display:YES];
    [self.window setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(self.openglWindow.frame.origin.x,self.openglWindow.frame.origin.y)];
    [self.window viewsNeedDisplay];
}
```